# Overwriting default bootstrap css with custom CSS only works with !important rule

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

basically I have already solved my problem, but I would like to understand why I needed to do it how I did it. Therefore I created a short example, available at https://jsfiddle.net/herbert_hinterberger/9x22u934/

Now I wanted to ask why I need to use the !important rule inside

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: #eae8e8 !important;
}
```

to change the color of .navbar-brand? As of my understanding the custom CSS should overwrite the bootstrap default css rules. But for any reason the bootstrap default CSS rules are applied before the custom CSS rules if I do not use the !important rule. See

[image]

Can anybody please explain why I need to use here the !important rule?

Best regards, 
Herbert

Comment: Just Include your css file after bootstrap .css file then no need to type !important

Comment: @user3756181: Thanks. I already did that and it works well, except for .navbar-brand. Also in the jsfiddle example you can see that other custom CSS rules are applied well without !important. Just .navbar-brand requires for any reason the !important rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `!important` every time.

The rule is, whatever css comes later is taken. So, if you have

```
.aClass {
    color:red;
}
```

in **red.css**

and

```
.aClass {
    color:blue;
}
```

in **blue.css**,
and you include **blue.css** after **red.css**, the text having `aClass` will be blue.

You only use `!important` when you want one rule to override everything else.

---

Edit: After the OP's comment, the actual answer to this question is this.

In the `bootstrap.css` file, we have something like:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #hashtag;
}
```

therefore, when you do:

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: #newHashtag;
}
```

it doesn't change the color of `.navbar-brand` that is invoked by `.navbar-default` (You use this class through `.navbar-default` in your HTML). Here, `.navbar-brand` is a descendant of `.navbar-default`. But, when you put in the `!important`, it tells all `.navbar-brand`s to change color.

So, if you do want to change the color of your `.navbar-brand`, try something like:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #newHashtag;
}
```

For more information, read up on *descendant selector combinators* in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. This also works well, except for .navbar-brand. Also in the jsfiddle example you can see that "later" (custom) CSS rules are applied well without !important. Just .navbar-brand requires for any reason the !important rule.

Comment: @HH. please see if the updated answer explains it. Thanks to you, I too learned something new today :D

Comment: Perfect. You got the point and thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to overwrite bootstrap CSS with your own, you need to include your custom CSS after bootstrap.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did that and it works well, except for .navbar-brand. Also in the jsfiddle example you can see that other custom CSS rules are applied well without !important. Just .navbar-brand requires for any reason the !important rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the css selector bootstrap is using '.navbar-header .navbar-brand' has more specificity than yours '.navbar-brand'
see this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
and try this

```
.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: #eae8e8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best explanation for your Question

**CASE: 1**

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="blue box"></div>

/*CSS*/
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

/*The Battle*/
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

In the Battle how wins? obviously last one i.e

```
.box {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

Background color red applied to div

Other Anwsers explain this case, writing custom css file after the bootstrap.css, it override bootstrap Styles

**CASE: 2**

ID vs. Class

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="box" id="box"></div>
    /*CSS*/
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

/*The Battle*/
#box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How Wins? obviously id Win, Id is declared as winner according to Rules of Specificity

Scores of elements according to specificity

- inline-style = 1000 points (decided by css Specificity)
- ID’s are worth a 100 points.
- Classes are worth 10 points.
- Elements are worth 1 point.

Example:

```
#content .sidebar .module li a{}
```

Score is :

```
#content =100; .sidebar, .module = 10 +10; li, a = 1+1
```

**Total: 122**

If we add one id at front as below We can overrides above mentioned style because the score of below mentioned style is 222

```
#main-container #content .sidebar .module li a{}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I learned something new. But actually the comment by Ranveer is the right answer.